# Access local app's API without http (within 1 Heroku dyno)

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, heroku

Currently I have two node processes that I need to run. One is my own custom app and another is iframely, another Node app that returns embed codes. Right now, I have the node app make requests to, say `http://localhost:8061/iframely?url=...`. But now, switching to Heroku, only 1 process in my app can accept HTTP requests (this is the process designated with `web:` in the `Procfile`, as I understand it).

To run iframely along side my app, do I have to create another app? Or can I have the two processes speak to each other bypassing http? Keeping in mind I don't want to devilry restructure iframely.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you have two totally different node processes running on different ports on your local. You want to deploy to heroku and reproduce this functionality. To accomplish this, you would deploy two heroku apps.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds from your description as if you have two separate node apps, and each one serves its own purpose.

Regardless of how these apps are implemented, the best way to handle this sort of thing is via multiple heroku apps. This is what they were designed for!

You can think of a Heroku app as a single-purpose web server. If you have one codebase that does something independent of another, create two Heroku apps. If you have 3 codebases that all do different things, make 3 Heroku apps.

In addition to this being the best way to handle this sort of thing in general (you get more reliability as each service has it's own servers), it's also cheaper: you get 1 free Heroku dyno **per app**, this means you'll have 2x's the free web servers you would have otherwise.